# What does an "a" mean in Class diagrams?

Tags: uml, document, class-diagram, visual-paradigm

After reversing Java code to Class diagram with Visual Paradigma on the class and package nodes is visualized an "a" on the upper left corner.
What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: Not 100% sure of my answer so I put it as a comment to suggest you the direction. As I recall in VP small "a" shown with the element indicated some kind of attachment related to that element. As Thomas Kilian already mentioned it has nothing to do with the UML itself, just a tool functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that they are not related to UML. In Visual Paradigm model elements are run in repository base which means the same model element can exist in multiple diagrams. The little icon "M" and "a" is to indicate the element is a Master or Auxiliary view. The different between Master and Auxiliary view is who can make change to the model structure. Consider that the same class exist in two diagrams, where in diagram A the class is inside package A, and in diagram B it is inside package B. If the class shape in diagram A with the "M" icon which means it is the master view, and its change on parent & child relationship will apply to model structure (i.e. move it from package A to package C), where the change on diagram B will not make affect to model structure. More detail about the concept of Model Elements and Views, also the Master and Auxiliary View can be found below.

[Model Elements and Views](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/1283/27/28894_modelelement.html)

[Master and Auxiliary View](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/1283/27/28895_masterviewan.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing defined in UML itself. This is an artifact created by the tool you are using.